# Find all the right triangles whose hypotenuse's length is an integer and the other two sides of which have lengths that are perfect squares

Tags: number-theory

Find all the right triangles whose hypotenuse's length is an integer and the other two sides of which have lengths that are perfect squares
This is how far i went:

Let $z$ be the hypothenuse of the triangle and let $y$ and $x$ be the other two sides.
Hence we have $x^2+y^2=z^2$
But $x$ and $y$ are perfect squares
Let $s$ and $r$ be some integers such that : $x=s^2$ and $y=r^2$
With the Pythagoras triplet , we get:
$s^2=p^2-q^2$
And $r^2=2pq$
And $z=p^2+q^2$
But i dont know what to do next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From L. E. Dickson, *History of the Theory of Numbers*, Volume II, Chapter XXII, page
$618$

> L. Euler$^{13}$ proved that $\,a^4+b^4\ne\square\,$ if $\,ab\ne0.\,$
> For, if $\,(a^2)^2+(b^2)^2=\square,\,$ where $\,a\,$ and $\,b\,$ are
> relatively prime, then $a^2=p^2-q^2,\, b^2=2pq,$ where $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime, one even and the other odd. By
> $\,p^2-q^2=\square,\, p\,$ is odd, whence $\,q\,$ is even. By $p(2q)=b^2,\,p\,$ and $\,2q\,$ are squares. By $\,p^2=a^2+q^2,\,$
> we get $\,p=m^2+n^2,\,$ $q=2mn,\,$ $m\,$ and $\,n\,$ relatively prime.
> Since $\,2q=\square,\,mn=\square$ and $m=x^2,\,n=y^2.\,$ Thus
> $\,x^4+y^4\,$ is a square $\,p,\,$ and $\,x, y\,$ are less than $a,b$.

This is a classic example of Fermat's method of infinite descent. By
the way, this result immediately implies that $\,a^4+b^4\ne c^4\,$ if
$\,ab\ne0.$ This is a variant of the case mentioned in the Wikipedia
article [Fermat's Last  Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem#Proofs_for_specific_exponents) section
on "Proofs for specific exponents"

> Only one relevant proof by Fermat has survived, in which he uses the technique of infinite descent to show that the area of a right triangle with integer sides can never equal the square of an integer. His proof
> is equivalent to demonstrating that the equation $$x^4-y^4=z^2$$ has
> no primitive solutions in integers (no pairwise coprime solutions). In
> turn, this proves Fermat's Last Theorem for the case $n=4,$ since the
> equation $a^4+b^4=c^4$ can be written as $c^4-b^4=(a^2)^2.$

Comment: So it's an infinite descent and there's no solution?